# ADS error 5047 with client dataset

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, advantage-database-server, tclientdataset

Reported Problem:

```
exception class   : AdsError
exception message : Error 5047: The transaction command was not in valid sequence. Not in a transaction.

main thread ($918):
00607cc5 +07d Boxer.exe    adscnnct  1576 +20 TAdsConnection.PerformRollback
00607d52 +002 Boxer.exe    adscnnct  1606  +0 TAdsConnection.Rollback
0062eab5 +09d Boxer.exe    DModule1   241 +10 TDM1.ApplyBoxer2Changes
```

Offending code:

```pascal
procedure TDM1.ApplyBoxer2Changes;
begin
  AdsConnection.BeginTransaction;
  try
    if cdsBoxes.ApplyUpdates(0) = 0 then
      AdsConnection.Commit
    else
      raise Exception.Create('Record changed by another user.');
  except
    on e: Exception do
    begin
      AdsConnection.Rollback;
      MessageDlg('An error occurred while attempting to save your changes:'+#13#10#10
        +e.Message, mtError, [mbOK], 0);
      cdsBoxes.CancelUpdates;
    end;
  end;
  cdsBoxes.Refresh;
end;
```

Where cdsBoxes is a TClientDataSet connected to a TDataSetProvider whose DataSet is a TAdsQuery with the same AdsConnection = TDM1.AdsConnection, and the following SQL:

```sql
SELECT * FROM Boxer2 WHERE Boxer1Id=:id
```

Can anyone see what is wrong with this code?

The 5047 error appears to be indicating that the transaction is no longer active when the Rollback method is called.

I haven't been able to reproduce the error myself; in my testing I'm able to add, edit and delete multiple records and then all the changes are either committed or the rollback occurs successfully.

Update: I have been able to reproduce it.  The problem occurs when there are 2 identical records in the table, so it is impossible to identify which one to update (there is no unique key on the table, DataSetProvider.UpdateMode = upWhereAll).

I'm not sure why the transaction is being cancelled automatically in that case, but a workaround to at least present a user-friendlier message is as follows:

```
procedure TDM1.ApplyBoxer2Changes;
begin
  AdsConnection.BeginTransaction;
  try
    if cdsBoxes.ApplyUpdates(0) = 0 then
      AdsConnection.Commit
    else
      raise Exception.Create('Record changed by another user.');
  except
    on e: Exception do
    begin
      if AdsConnection.TransactionActive then
      begin
        AdsConnection.Rollback;
        MessageDlg('An error occurred while attempting to save your changes:'+#13#10#10
          +e.Message, mtError, [mbOK], 0);
      end
      else
      begin
        MessageDlg('A data integrity error occurred while attempting to save your changes.'+#13#10#10
        +'Please report this to the help desk.', mtError, [mbOK], 0);
      end;
      cdsBoxes.CancelUpdates;
    end;
  end;
  cdsBoxes.Refresh;
end;
```

Comment: +1 for interesting q, to which I can't immediately see the answer I'm afraid  However I have a vague recollection of somebody asking here within the past 2-3 weeks about a TDataSet problem involving an "invalid transaction context" or words to that effect on some back-end operation, so it might be worth searching around for that.